# How to refer another label in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a way to refer a label (in current Dockerfile or inherited labels) in a Docker file? For example lets say I want to have a Dockerfile like below

```
FROM nginx

LABEL firstlabel="first label"
LABEL secondlabel="I want to use value of ${firstlabel}"
```

where I want to use the value of label "firstlabel" in the secondlabel. Is that possible? I tried using the ${} variable but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [build arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) and [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) to do this kind of thing.

You should be aware though that there are two phases for every container i. e. building and running. Labels defined in a Dockerfile are associated to an image so are generally set at build time although you can set/overwrite labels on `docker run` using `--label <label-name>=<label-value>` option. So passing a value for an environment variable that is used within a label to `docker run` will  **not** update that label as the label is set on build time.

Consider the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
# build argument of name buildDate
ARG buildDate
# environment variables for author name
ENV AUTHOR_FNAME=John \
    AUTHOR_LNAME=McClain
# we can use both in our labels
LABEL testlabel="Author: ${AUTHOR_FNAME} ${AUTHOR_LNAME}"\
      buildDate=${buildDate}
```

Now build the container and provide the build arguments:

```sh
docker build -t test/test --build-arg buildDate=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d') .
```

Run the container:

```sh
docker run --name test -it --rm test/test sh
```

No open up another Terminal session and use the following command to inspect the labels:

```sh
docker inspect test --format='{{json .Config.Labels}}'
```

Result:

```json
{"buildDate":"2022-04-28","testlabel":"Author: John McClain"}
```

You can now type `exit` into to `sh` to leave the container and it will automatically be removed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am aware of using the ENV and ARG, my question was specific to referencing other LABEL values.

Comment: As far as I know that is not possible. To be honest, I don't think it is even necessary because the purpose of labels is to describe the image or certain aspects of it briefly and precisely. Consider for example the [OCI standard labels](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/annotations.md). Re-using labels would therefore result in unnecessarily duplicating information. But I suppose one could have different opinions on that.

Comment: Where I am coming from is lets say I create my image from multiple parent base images and lets say all of them use the OCI standard labels as you rightly pointed out. So the last images label value for org.opencontainers.image.description (again this is just an example) would overwrite all other images value for the same label. Ideally I would like to preserve the parent descriptions and keep appending to it so that from the final image, its clear what all other stuff is built in. But looks like that's not possible

Comment: Ah, I see. I can certainly understand why you'd wanna do this. Maybe we'll see something like this in the future or someone smarter than us knows how you could do that now already :)